# Trying to fetch an image via GitHub api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, github-api

I'm trying to fetch an image via the GitHub api and it consistently shows as a placeholder image.

My component looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

async function getImage(folder, text) {
  const url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/contents/' + folder + "/" + text;
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: "blob" });
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

export default function (props) {
  const [image, setImage] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {   
    async function fetchData() {
      const imageData = await getImage(props.folder, props.text)
      setImage(imageData)
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {props.text}
      <img src={image}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Obviously  and  is replaced with proper values.

Comment: You need to turn that blob into a temporary URL but why not link to the image directly?